# Maven missing classes

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I created a basic maven project in eclipse and I'm getting errors in my pom.xml that classes are missing, I checked the folder that it was looking in and the file paths don't match what I have and the classes don't exist.. My path goes up to: C:\Users\user.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\shared and it is stating there is a /filtering/ folder which I don't have. I have the latest maven and m2eclipse installed.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably a bad installations (incomplete download or missing jars). I suggest you delete the

> C:\Users\user.m2\

folder completely and run `mvn clean install` again. Maven will fetch the jars for you. Also try to refresh the maven project from within eclipse. Right click on project -> maven -> update project. Sometimes eclipse has this issue.